# Reset Windows Live account for Windows 8

Tags: sync, windows-live-messenger, windows-live, windows-8

I have used the German release preview of Windows 8 and after installing the RTM available via MSDN my apps which were synced got automatically installed. However I have the English version of Win 8 yet some apps were in German and then something screwed them and I have to reinstall.

However I wonder how I can reset my account so that I can start "from scratch" the next time I install Win 8 **WITHOUT deleting my Live account as I have Office bound to it and my MSN Messenger contacts which I do not want to readd**.

Comment: @AceLegend: Yeah, but it doesn't.

Comment: switch to local user account. then, when picking a new account as login, you will be prompted for a new e-mail

Answer (score 0):

Even though some time has passed since the question was asked, you may try this procedure:

First disable syncing the syncing control panel on every machine you have linked to your account:

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and search for "Sync your settings", disable what you want in there, or syncing altogether.

[image: Syncing configuration]

- Once you have stopped syncing of settings from all your devices go to [this place in SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/P.mvc#!/win8personalsettingsprivacy/) and choose to remove the settings that are backed up online.

Done, after that your account will not contain your settings and you can use it in a fresh machine without bringing all your applications and customizations.

Comment: This does not reset my account, it only disables all synchronization and this is not what I am looking for.